# Pusher Error - Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, push-notification, pusher

Getting a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on my pusherTrigger method

It's a simple messaging system, where one user sends another user a message and the receiver should get a notification for it. I have a `compose_message` action that is supposed push the message onto the channel `private-incomingMessages`.

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(window.EmberPusher.Bindings, window.EmberPusher.ClientEvents, {
  content: {},
  logPusherEvents: true,
  PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS: {'messageChannel': ['client-compose-message'],
                       'incomingMessages': ['client-user-messages']},
  actions: {
    compose_message: function(){
        var self = this, content = this.get('messageContent');
        self.get('pusher.connection').pusherTrigger('incomingMessages', 'client-user-messages', {'message': content}); //not registering pusherTrigger as a method
    },

    clientUserMessages: function(){
        console.log("client user messages is working!");
    }
});
```

Let me know if you need more info. Please help if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what is your question? You don't have the auth route on your backend.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I wanted private channels. I updated my initial question using public ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can only trigger client events on [private channels](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels) so you'll need to use private channels (*I see you had them and then removed them*). See the [Pusher client event docs](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#trigger-events).

You'll therefore need to [authenticate your private channel](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints) and thus you'll need the `/pusher/auth` endpoint.

In order to create the `private-` channel name the EmberPusher docs suggested you build up the subscription hash in a controller `init` function.

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend(window.EmberPusher.Bindings, window.EmberPusher.ClientEvents, {
  init: {
    // build subscription hash here
  },
  ...
});
```

As per the [EmberPusher docs](https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher#example-controller) you'll need to `camelise` event names so I think `compose_message` should be `clientComposeMessage`.

Finally, the code for calling `pusherTrigger` doesn't look right. The EmberPusher docs show:

```
this.pusherTrigger(this.get('channelName'), eventName, this.get('data'));
```

In your example it looks like `pusherTrigger` is being called on the connection object.